# Get Phone region name programmatically

Tags: android, location, region

I have to get phone no region (means from which region this no belongs) programmatically. I searched lot and didn't find anyway then I thought to get current location through network provider name but it return city name. Actually 1st I have to get phone no region if it not possible then through network provider how can we get region of current location. Please suggest me.

Comment: Get the first few digits and compare them to the ones here: http://countrycode.org/

Comment: Thanks @g00dy I didn't get it actually will u elaborate this plz

Comment: Ok,, you have the phone number - right? Someting like +123 3434 3423 etc. the first few digits after the "+" sign (which is in fact equivalent to "00" when you call) and make a database with the country codes, then compare those. The Network Location is no good, if you have an american phone number and you're calling from Germany for example.

Comment: Actaully i have to get ret region code of India only

Comment: So, if it starts with "+91" - that's India :)

Comment: No not like that if it's indian no then from which region like east,north,south or west

Comment: Well, that's not obtainable with the phone codes. You'll have to use location (GPS or NETWORK) and see where this person is.

Comment: yeah but i have requirement of person region code is this possible ?

Comment: Well, it depends from the numer the person's using. If it's a mobile number, then the region can not be determined, but if it's stationnary - it can be determined.

Comment: What about getting state name ?

Answer (score 1):

Try Telephony Service.

```
TelephonyManager telman=(TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

a lot of info can retrieve as,

```
telman.getNetworkOperatorName();
telman.getSimSerialNumber();
telman.getLine1Number();
telman.getSubscriberId();
```

etc.

There is a method, `telman.getCellLocation();` . I didn't try it yet, may be you can try.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the name of the Current Network Operator to which the Android phone is currently connected is to get hold of the android.telephony.TelephonyManager and get it from there:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager =((TelephonyManager) Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));
String operatorName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

similarly the sim operator can be retrieved by using:

```
String operatorName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
```